# how to link new domain with amazon web services

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I got got a new domain that I want to link to aws.

I've already have EC2 instance running.

I'm using Route53 for DNS, and opened 2 records: www.domain.com and domain.com

I updated the register company about the new dns servers from route53.

I do have an elastic IP I linked to my EC2 instance.

the problem is that i can't reach my web site.
I guess I'm missing some parts.

did I miss anything along the way?

EDIT: I can reach my site using the public IP I got from Amazon.
But I can't reach it using my domain.

how can i tell what breaks it?

Comment: Does your security group have port 80 open and a web server of some sort running on that port?

Comment: yes, Apache is running and I have ssh rdp and http ports open

Comment: Does the site repsond if you access the site via ip address?

Comment: no ping to elastic ip

Comment: Ping will only work if your security group allows icmp. If apache is running I assume you have access to the instance. If you use that ip address in your browser does it work?

Comment: no response, what security group settings you recommend?

Comment: Port 80 should be open to at least your ip, if not open to all. Some AMI's might have an internal firewall that is blocking port 80 by default. (windows firewall or iptables). Apache should not be configured to listen to the public ip since its not mapped directly to the instance.

Comment: this was related to http group.
I opened it to all.
what is the recommend settings for http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to check:

1. Have you definatley set the namservers correctly with the domain registrar?
2. Have you added the elastic IP address in Route 53?

Some other things that you could possibly check are the firewall settings. This is unlikely the case if you can access the site via the IP address.

Do you know what IP address the domain is resolving to. Is this correct?

Comment: I added A record in route53 that links to my elastic IP.
and added the correct CNAME record for my domain + updated 4 DNS server on my registrar

Comment: Does the domain name resolve to the elastic IP address? (You can use something like http://moonsy.com/domain-ip/ to find out)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can have look at this blog it will explain lot of things 
http://geekospace.com/mapping-aws-ec2-instance-to-your-domain-in-godaddy/